# How can I speed up iteration through this transformed numpy array?

Tags: python, performance, numpy, nested-loops

Below is a partial class definition for a map of 2D isometric tiles to be rendered using pyglet.

```
class Map(object):

    origin = 0
    drytile = tile.dry
    wettile = tile.wet

    def __init__(self, left=8, right=8):
        self.grid = np.array(([None] * left, [None] * right), dtype=object)
        self._setup_grid()

    def __iter__(self):
        """return tiles in the order in which they should be rendered"""
        # get number of diagonals
        ndiags = (np.max(self.grid.shape) * 2) -\
                 (1 + (np.max(self.grid.shape) - np.min(self.grid.shape)))

        # get iterator to go through diagonals in back-to-front order
        offsets = xrange(-(ndiags / 2), ndiags / 2 + 1)

        # iterate in render order
        for off in offsets:
            for tile in np.flipud(self.grid).diagonal(off)[::-1]:
                yield tile
```

These tiles need to be rendered back-to-front, as per this diagram:

[image: Tile render order. Origin is at the top corner]

In my class definition, the origin refers to the top most tile (tile `a`), thus the `left` dimension defined in the class is the vector along `[a b d g]` and the  `right` dimension is the vector along `[a c f j]`.

This is a speed-critical part of my application as I intend to render a large number of tiles.  Is there a faster way to iterate through the tiles in the specified order?  Might eliminating the nested loop help?

Thanks very much!

Answer (score 0):

I would order the data structure first. If you order the vector then iterating will be faster.

In general using ordered data-structures is good for this sort of thing.

If you are manipulating the structure for whatever reason, you need to perform an "Ordered-insert" or removal, which is slower. The trade off for using ordered datastructures is on insert and removal, and since a board shouldn't change much it looks like you can only with with ordered data-structures.

Comment: Are you talking about the `np.flipud(self.grid).diagonal(off)[::-1]` statement?  If so it's not immediately obvious to me how to go about ordering the array.  Do you have any suggestions?